# There is a formal definition of mathematical space?

Tags: reference-request, definition

Yesterday I was searching for a formal definition of *mathematical space*, then I found it [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)), where the definition rely in the concept of *mathematical structure*.

But I didnt found a formal definition of mathematical structure (it [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_structure) is very vague).

Then I dont know if exists a formal definition of mathematical space, or if this concept is just historical/utilitary.

If someone can clarify this question, through some reference or by any other way, I will be grateful.

Comment: There is no universal definition for the word *space*.  The word may mean different things depending on the context - a probability space, vector space, topological space, etc.  Similarly 'structure' has no precise definition.  These aren't words that make sense in the context of formal proofs, but are nonetheless useful concepts for humans speaking about math at a high-level.

Comment: I worry that you may have misread the subtle grammar of the sentence at their first Wikipedia link: "A space is a set with some structure", but not every "set with some structure" is a "space". Robert Israel's post about concrete categories may cover all of the "sets with some structure", both spaces and non-spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no formal definition of the word "(mathematical) space", and this is not a term that is used with any precise formal meaning.  The "definition" you found on Wikipedia is a definition in the sense of a dictionary entry, not a definition in a mathematical or logical sense.

(To be clear, there are many types of "spaces" that do have formal definitions, like vector spaces, topological spaces, etc.  But there is no overarching precise mathematical concept of "space" that these are special cases of or anything like that.  You can probably find someone somewhere who has written down a formal definition of a "mathematical space", perhaps along the lines of Robert Israel's suggestion of an object in a concrete category.  But this is not the way people commonly use the term.)

Answer (score 2):

[Category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) is an attempt to formalize the notion of mathematical structure.  So you might consider a "space" to be an object in a [concrete category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_category).

Comment: I wouldn't call a group a "space", though.

Comment: ... unless perhaps you identify it with the homogeneous space $G/\{e\}$.  But is there a reason for not calling it a "space", or just tradition?

Comment: your answer is very useful (indeed the implicit spirit of the question is the ways to formalize or approach formally the concept "mathematical space") but I think the answer that fit better to the question was done by @Eric. Anyway the "perfect" answer would be the fusion of both because they complement very well.

Comment: @Robert, I would say that the word "space" conjures up the image of a location where some semblance of $\mathbb R^n$ is preserved: combining vectors or neighborhoods or measures of subsets, etc. "Probability space" and "sample space" don't feel great to me, and calling an arbitrary concrete category a space seems to divorce all connection to the everyday meaning of the English word "space".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that most things called a "space" in mathematics is either a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) of some sort, a [topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space) of some sort, or both. My interpretation agrees with [the hierarchy diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)#/media/File:Mathematical_implication_diagram_eng.jpg) on [the Wikipedia page for "space"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)).

A topological space is just a set (whose elements are called "points") and [a consideration of some subsets of the set to be "open"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Definition_via_open_sets) (think unions of of [open-disks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)) in $\mathbb R^n$) where unions and finite intersections of open sets are open.

A vector space is just a set (whose elements are called "vectors") where you can add and subtract vectors and multiply them by numbers (elements from any [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), technically, but $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are common) and the operations [act and interact in the way you would hope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition).

Every other space builds on one or both of these ideas. For example, a "normed vector space" adds in the concept of the "length" of a vector to vector spaces. A "metric space" adds in the concept of "distance between points" to a topological space.

---

There are other instances of the word "space" that are not really referenced on the wikipedia page mentioned by the OP: "[probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space)" and relatedly, "[sample space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space)". Also, "[measure spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition)".

Comment: $G$-space, coset space, configuration space, algebraic space...

Comment: @RobertIsrael, in my experience, all of those terms have been used just in cases where they refer to topological spaces with extra conditions and/or structure. It was not my intention to give a complete list of all the uses that fall under "topological space of some sort", and I'm sure I haven't encountered all such uses myself in any case.